# Where is the public key/output for the miner reflected on the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, transaction-fees, block-explorer, mining-theory

One of the ways that I can understand how Monero demonstrably works, despite the opacity of the blockchain, is that the inputs used in transactions (whether mixin decoys, or the actual one-time public key being spent) are always visibly created in a prior block.

When looking at a block explorer (moneroblocks.info, in this case), it appears that I can only see the outputs created for the recipient(s) and change.  I do not see an output of transaction fees created for the miner.  A miner must receive the fees in form of a spendable output somehow, I would think.

Where is the miner's missing output?  Is there something I may be misunderstanding about the process?  I mean, I can see a coinbase transaction for that block, but doesn't the coinbase transaction only reflect the newly mined monero?  Or are the transaction fees included in coinbase output(s)?

(Not that it necessarily matters, but I figure I should clarify that I added up the inputs, and I added up the outputs - of a pre-RingCT transaction - and found that the outputs add up to less than the inputs by the amount of the transaction fee.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction fees and block reward are sent together as the miner reward. For example, the block [1229239](https://xmrchain.net/block/1229239) has one non-coinbase transaction whose fee is 0.01. The block reward is 8.8642, so the miner reward is 0.01 + 8.8642 = 8.8742.